# How do I put my content in a box?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and CSS, but I have managed to create a basic website, I have a small menu on the top that consists of links directing you to the different pages such as "Home", "About" and "Contact". The site is only gonna consist of information and pictures so it's good enough.

Anyway, I feel like the site would look better if I could put the content in a box and have the background on the sides because the text doesn't show up that well even when putting black outlines on the letters. What I'd like to do is basically put my menu, logo and text inside a box like this site: http://www.kakservice.se/?gclid=Cj0KEQiAzai0BRCs2Yydo8yptuIBEiQAN3_lFqaNO2scD5hQCDW0jBWNIAOAyPrZRG20X2a1LsBTIrcaAko68P8HAQ (Couldn't remember a site in English with this design, but I suppose it's unimportant.) and preferably adding a shadow at the border.

So how would I go about this? I have searched online, but I don't know exactly what to search for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: without your current code we can't really help much

Comment: @Minzkraut But can be helped. `:)`

Comment: but we're all lazy and don't want to start with nothing... normally

Comment: Why is that? I am merely wondering what type of code I need in order to make this happen. I don't have any div or anything that you could add anything to. I would need to do that from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is, wrap all the contents of your `<body>` tag inside a wrapper like:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <!-- Everything inside body. -->
</div>
```

And add this following CSS:

```css
body {background: url("bg.jpg") center center repeat;}
#wrap {width: 80%; margin: auto;}
```

You can replace the `bg.jpg` with the background of your choice.

An example of what's before is:

```css
body {
  background: url("http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/grunge-tiled-background-6169673.jpg") center center repeat;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#wrap {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 15px;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <h1>Welcome to My Site</h1>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! That's what I'm looking for, took me a little bit to get it right, but it seems to work pretty well. Previously I had just photoshopped a white part on my background image which looked the part, but I realized after a while that the text will not move with the background so if you minimized the window half the text will in the box and the other text will move outside for example. Is it possible to add a shadow to this? I'm guessing it should work in CSS, right?

Comment: @KnugenavSwärje Do you want the background to stay in the same place?